# Qual a origem e significado da expressão "O Preguiçoso trabalha dobrado"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, ditados, proverbios

Qual a origem e significado da expressão "O Preguiçoso trabalha dobrado"
Remonta a que século?

Comment: Por preguiça não faz direito e, assim, acaba tendo que refazer: por isso  "dobrado".

Comment: Interessante. Pode colocar como resposta?

Comment: Fi-lo, mas como não conheço a origem, é uma resposta incompleta. Tomara que alguém faça uma contribuição melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por preguiça não faz direito e, assim, acaba tendo que refazer: por isso "dobrado".

Mas não conheço a origem da expressão.